# How can I prevent cognito from sending automatic emails?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito

I have a lambda on the `Custom message` trigger, this is the handler:

```
def forgot_password(event, context):

    boto_client = boto3.client('ses')
    html_body = get_html_file_from_bucket()
    email = event['request']['userAttributes']['email']
    code_parameter = event['request']['codeParameter']

    url_data = {
        "username": email,
        "code_parameter": code_parameter
    }

    encoded_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(url_data)
    set_new_password_link = f'{os.environ["CONCIL_SET_NEW_PASSWORD_ENDPOINT"]}?{encoded_params}'
    html_body = html_body.replace(
        "{replace_me}", set_new_password_link)

    if event["userPoolId"] == os.environ['COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID']:
        if event["triggerSource"] == "CustomMessage_ForgotPassword":
            set_new_password_email_response = boto_client.send_email(
                Destination={
                    'ToAddresses': [
                        email
                    ],
                },
                Message={
                    'Body': {
                        'Html': {
                            'Charset': "utf-8",
                            'Data': html_body,
                        },
                    },
                    'Subject': {
                        'Charset': "utf-8",
                        'Data': "Redefina a sua senha",
                    },
                },
                Source=os.environ["CONCIL_NOTIFICATION_EMAIL"]
            )
            modify_response(
                event, "emailSubject", None)
            modify_response(
                event, "emailMessage", None)
            print("SES RESPONSE")
            print(set_new_password_email_response)
        else:
            return event
    print("EVENT")
    print(event)
return event
```

As you can see, I override the default sending behavior by sending through AWS SES manually, and I do this because of the hateful buggy default behavior of the cognito/SES relationship (Even though I set the emailMessage as the HTML body, the message gets replaced by the default one).

Problem is, now I get 2 emails: The correct one, and the automatic unnecessary one. So, how can I suppress the automatic one? On the userpool configuration, this is the current default:

```
"SmsVerificationMessage": "Your verification code is {####}. ",
    "EmailVerificationMessage": "Seu código de verificação é {####}.",
    "EmailVerificationSubject": "Seu código de verificação",
    "VerificationMessageTemplate": {
        "SmsMessage": "Your verification code is {####}. ",
        "EmailMessage": "Seu código de verificação é {####}.",
        "EmailSubject": "Seu código de verificação",
        "DefaultEmailOption": "CONFIRM_WITH_CODE"
    },
```

I can't find anywhere on the docs a way to completely remove this annoying automatic email.

Comment: Maybe try raising an exception?

Comment: @jellycsc, this is an insane idea, I like it HUAHUAHUA I'll try.

Comment: xxxxxxDDDDDDDDD

Comment: @jellycsc worked like a charm, you Sir, are a genius. We have a name for this kind of solution in my country (Brazil), and is "gambiarra". The developers on AWS should be more considerate of the poor developers that use their services.

Comment: TIL. Yeah, my previous experience with Cognito was pretty rough too. LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to OP's comment, the solution is to raise an exception before the lambda function returns.